# is it possible to make NFC payment app for iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nfc

I have read that from iPhone 7- iOS 11, it can read NFC tags, but cannot write NFC. As far as I know, for NFC payments, the phone must transfer some data (card number, id, etc) to the terminal. So I'm curious if it is possible to make NFC payment app like apple pay. Any relevant reference source is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not provide a public API for writing NFC data. It is not possible to create your own payment app without additional hardware

Comment: what do you mean by additional hardware?

Comment: I think Paypal signed contract with apple to use it, so should I do the same here to achieve that:)

Comment: No, PayPal can accept payments using their external PayPal Here reader that connects via Bluetooth.  There are no payment solutions available using native hardware aside from Apple Pay.

Comment: ok, thank you a lot. I'll go and read more about pay pal here.